# Is it possible to unlink a CN account temporarily and re-link it later to register the games afterwards?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, club-nintendo

At the moment I hit platinum status but want to avoid downloading Pokemon Bank and Steel Diver to save those coins for the next CN year (that starts on July). I was wondering, could it be possible to unlink my Club Nintendo account from my 3DS, download the games, and link it a couple of months down the line to "save" those coins for later? Or will I lose those coins if the 3DS is not linked to a CN account?

Answer (score 1):

If you unlink your account, it is going to assume you won't have one, and if you download the games from the e-shop, you won't get the coins. (The shop doesn't go back and check for past purchases.)

Unfortunately, the only way to really "hold back" coins from purchases is to buy physical games, and then keep the codes somewhere until after the date for Platinum/Gold level turnover for the year.